# Scroll up UITextField on Next

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uiview, uiscrollview

I am creating a "sign in" and "create account" form for my iOS app. I successfully implemented the scrolling up of the UITextField when it is hidden. However, now that I implemented the "next" button the "UIKeyboardDidShowNotification" is not called because the keyboard is never dismissed. I need the keyboardWasShow method called so I can check if the active UITextField is hidden or not.

```
   // Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
  {
NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

// If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
// Your application might not need or want this behavior.
CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;

CGPoint pointInSuperview = [self.view convertPoint:self.activeField.frame.origin fromView:self.scrollView];

aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
//added 10 to y axis because tip of origin was outside of keyboard
pointInSuperview.y +=20;

if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, pointInSuperview)) {
    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, pointInSuperview.y - (kbSize.height -15));
    NSLog(@"it is not in the rect");
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
   }
}
```

and I have an observer

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
```

and after I implemented my Next button (see below) the keyboardWasShown method is not called so it never checks if the active UITextField is hidden.

```
   //functionality for next action
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
   if (textField == self.emailAddress) {
     [self.fullName becomeFirstResponder];
     [self keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)UIKeyboardDidShowNotification];


 }
 else if (textField == self.fullName) {
       [self.password becomeFirstResponder];
 }
else if (textField == self.password) {
    [self.confirmPassword becomeFirstResponder];
}
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}
```

What would be the best approach to call keyboardWasShown when the user clicks the Next button?  I tried making it a public method but I kept getting errors when I tried to call it manually.

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid this is to resign the responder prior to setting the next responder, which will ensure that the `keyboardWasShown` notification was called. For example, based on your code you could use the following:

```
...
else if (textField == self.fullName) {
    [self.fullName resignFirstResponder];
    [self.password becomeFirstResponder];
}
...
```

Whilst this might seem odd, it should be noted that the keyboard doesn't actually disappear/reappear.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to look into [this](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)

If your fields arent in a table the same sort of logic can apply to other cases.